# Editting a Search Results Web part changing the result source CSOM

Tags: web-part, client-object-model, powershell

I am doing some CSOM powershell to edit a search results web part and change the result source. Don't really know where to start with this as I am new to the world of CSOM powershell. Any help would be appreciated.